# Running code in Python modules without being relative to the running script

Tags: python, path

This question has very probably been asked before, but I can't seem to figure out key terms to search to find an answer, so I apologize for asking this again if it has been asked. Basically, I have the following directory structure:

```
root_dir/
├── main.py
└── sub_dir/
    └── module.py
    └── utils.py
    └── file.txt
```

I use `module.py` in `main.py`, which is the script that I'm running. In `module.py`, I want to use a function from `utils.py`. I have to do `from sub_dir.utils import function` instead of `from utils import function` even though `utils.py` and `module.py` are in the same directory.
On a similar note, if I want to open `file.txt` from a function defined in `utils.py`, I'm having to do `open('subdir/file.txt', r)` rather than `open('file.txt', r)` in the function

Answer (score 0):

you can use `from .utils import function` inside `module.py`

its called [relative import](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-and-relative-imports-in-python/)